# Proof of Harnack inequality for parabolic equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I see a Harnack  inequation in a Chinese book. But there is not proof in it.  I try to find the proof. But in other book,  only proof of different form Harnack inequality can be found. So I ask here for the proof of following Harnack inequality.

---

**Harnack inequality** :  For any $\lambda >1, R>0, x_0\in \mathbb R^n,t_0\ge 0$, $u$ is the non-negative weak solution of
$$
u_t=\Delta u ~~~~~~(x,t)\in B_R(x_0)\times(t_0, t_0+\lambda R^2)
$$
then, there is constant $C(n,\lambda )$ such that
$$
\inf\limits_{B_{_{R/2}}~~(x_0)}   u(x,t_0+\lambda R^2)\ge Cu(x_0, t_0 +R^2)
$$
where $B_{_{R/2}}~~(x_0)=\{x\in \mathbb R^n : |x-x_0|<\frac{R}{2}\}$.

---

I know the proof of Harnack inequality is  a little fussy. So just tell me which book has the proof of above Harnack inequality is enough. Thanks.

Comment: There's a proof of it in Evans' PDE book on page 393 from the 2nd edition.